# Using FileReader() to read bytes in older browsers with support issues

Tags: javascript

If one searches `File` on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=File) and expands `show all`, it's evident that older browsers (e.g. Android) have the following issues:

> Does not have FileReader support.
>
> Does not support the File constructor.

I want to understand what the first statement means in practice.

For instance, I'm receiving a file via an HTML input element like so:

```
var img_file = e.target.files[0];
```

Note that `img_file` is an object of type `File`.

Next, I'm reading the first few bytes of the file using a `FileReader()` object, and then determining the mime type:

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = validate_file;//validates the file's mime type
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(img_file.slice(0,4));
```

Does "**Does not have FileReader support**" imply that the statements above will give an error? If so, are there any workarounds for unsupportive browsers? I'd love to see an illustrative example around such workarounds (if they exist).

*Note: Please use pure JS for the scope of this question, and sans any 3rd party libraries.*

Comment: it could mean a lot of things.

Comment: Seems to contradict the FileReader API entry below which mentions support for that from v3 onwards for the android browser. This site is useful but I don't know accurate it is. https://caniuse.com/#info_about - it's just one person's set of tests. Not vendor-supplied support info or anything.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Browser_compatibility has what is probably a more reliable list. Of course, you could always try it for yourself.

Comment: @ADyson: thanks for the MDN link, I've seen that. Also see the mobile section for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#Browser_compatibility. To me, it sure sounds like `FileReader()` works, but can't make use of `File()` objects since those are unsupported? If it's something like that, what would be a way to ensure no errors are thrown and the code falls back elegantly in case of incompatibility?